# failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have one opinion class which contain the likes for that opinion and votes. when I try to fetch the opinion the array of Likes for that particular opinion not get load, it gives `"failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.opinion.model.Opinion.opinionLikes, could not initialize proxy - no Session"`. I have tried to change the fetchtype to eager but then I got error `"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.returns.CollectionReturnImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.loader.plan.spi.Fetch"`. I have also tried using @jsonignore but noting work. It also has another @manyToOne mapping for user which I am getting. Don't know what is Wrong Please Help, thanks a lot.

here is the snippet of my mapping for entities.

opinion.java

```
@JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userOpinion")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<OpinionLikeDislikeShare> opinionLikes = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Users users;
```

OpinionLikeDislikeShare.java

```
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "opinionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Opinion userOpinion;
```

users.java

```
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Opinion> opinion;
```

My Query

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getConnection().getCriteriaBuilder(); 
CriteriaQuery<Opinion> query = builder.createQuery(Opinion.class); 
Root<Opinion> root = query.from(Opinion.class); 
Expression<Long> friends = root.get(Opinion_.USER_ID); 
Predicate predicate = friends.in(usersFriend(userId)); 
query.select(root).where(predicate).orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("opinionPostDate")));
TypedQuery<Opinion> transform = manager.getConnection().createQuery(query).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(50); 
list = transform.getResultList();
```

Comment: Could you add the method that fetches the opinions?

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getConnection().getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<Opinion> query = builder.createQuery(Opinion.class);
   Root<Opinion> root = query.from(Opinion.class);
   Expression<Long> friends = root.get(Opinion_.USER_ID);
   Predicate predicate = friends.in(usersFriend(userId));
   query.select(root).where(predicate).orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("opinionPostDate")));
   TypedQuery<Opinion> transform = manager.getConnection().createQuery(query).setFirstResult(0)
     .setMaxResults(50);
   list = transform.getResultList();`

Comment: Add it to the post in order to see it well formatted